# How can a neural network architecture be visualized with Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, visualization, keras

I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import keras
from keras.models import model_from_yaml

model_file_path = 'model-301.yaml'
weights_file_path = 'model-301.hdf5'

# Load network
with open(model_file_path) as f:
    yaml_string = f.read()
model = model_from_yaml(yaml_string)
model.load_weights(weights_file_path)
model.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Visualize
from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
```

However, this gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/moose/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/visualize_util.py", line 7, in <module>
    if not pydot.find_graphviz():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_graphviz'
```

How can I fix this?

Note: The hdf5 and the YAML file can be found [on Github](https://github.com/TensorVision/MediSeg/tree/master/AP3/model-301).

Comment: See also: [How do you visualize neural network architectures?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/12851/8820)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is also referenced on the [issues page](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3210) of the keras project.
You need to install a version of `pydot` <= 1.1.0 because the function `find_graphviz` was [removed](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/commit/bc639e76b214b1795ebd6263680ee55d9d4fca9f#diff-44fda7721399b25e8cb06471016a3454) in version 1.2.0. Alternatively you could install [pydot-ng](https://github.com/pydot/pydot-ng) instead, which is [recommended](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/visualize_util.py#L2) by the keras developers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already installed `pydot` python package - try to install it. If you have `pydot` reinstallation should help with your problem.

Comment: `pydot` is installed in version 1.2.2. Reinstalling it didn't help.