# Keras or Tensorflow function to draw a 3D diagram of a neural network structure?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

When creating a neural network with Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
...
```

the function `model.summary` helps to get the big picture of the structure.

To get a better idea of the structure, **is there a function in Keras or Tensorflow (or another library) to automatically generate a 3D diagram of the structure?** like this:

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

Generating such a diagram file would be totally possible from the `model` object.

**TL;DR:**

- INPUT: a Keras `model` variable
- OUTPUT: a PNG image

---

PS:

- I already know this online tool: http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html and this question [How to draw Deep learning network architecture diagrams?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14899/how-to-draw-deep-learning-network-architecture-diagrams) but here the idea would be to generate this automatically from Keras.
- Linked but not identical: [How do you visualize neural network architectures?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-do-you-visualize-neural-network-architectures)
  .
- Different to [How can a neural network architecture be visualized with Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442107/how-can-a-neural-network-architecture-be-visualized-with-keras)
- Linked project: https://github.com/stared/keras-sequential-ascii
- Linked article: [Simple diagrams of convoluted neural networks](https://medium.com/inbrowserai/simple-diagrams-of-convoluted-neural-networks-39c097d2925b)
- Doing `from keras.utils import plot_model` `plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)` already gives something but it's not 3D:

  [image]

  Note: add this for Windows: `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin'` after installing `Graphviz` if you want to use `plot_model`.

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about this:
https://keras.io/visualization/

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

This saves the structure of your model with input and output tensors as png.
But unfortunately only the scheme, not three-dimensional

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's already something but indeed, it's not very detailed and not 3D: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2VeE.png